# Getting video info (width, height, duration) using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to validate video on the client side and check the video's width, height and duration. Just checking the file extension isn't enough; it has to make sure the correct codec and wrapper is used. How would I do this?

Comment: You know, that you need to implement such a feature twice? The real check should be done server-side after the upload.

Comment: yes.. we need to check on client side.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<video id="my_id" src="music.mp4"></video>

var video_id = document.getElementById("my_id"); video_id.videoHeight;
video_id.videoWidth;
```

Comment: yes I already saw this, but you know, not all browser version support html 5.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

```
<video id="foo" src="foo.mp4"></video>

var vid = document.getElementById("foo");
vid.videoHeight; // returns the intrinsic height of the video
vid.videoWidth; // returns the intrinsic width of the video
```

Source (HTML5 spec): http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#video

Comment: yes I already saw this, but you know, not all browser version support html 5.